# Swift - override Edit button function

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a UITableView, which comes prefitted with an Edit button (`UITableView.editButtonItem()`). When pressed, it toggles to "Done", and you get those red minus signs next to entries for when you want to delete them.

I want to attach custom code to the button so that when you click it, you don't get the red minus signs. When in edit mode, whenever you click on an entry, it brings up a UIActionSheet or a UIAlertController to allow you to make the changes.

So, I want to override the Edit button so that when clicked:

- The red minus "Delete" icons don't show up
- The cells become selectable.

I've tried creating a custom UIBarButtonItem, but that's a terrible walkaround. I think what I want is do-able, I'm just not sure how.

Answer (score 0):

Use `delegate` for `UIViewController` and make custom code on the events of that button. If it is on every row you must attach `tap action` from the code during `cell` generation.
I myself would preffer to have `custom class`.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out which methods to call:

```
// The following two functions remove the red minus sign
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCellEditingStyle {
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyle.None
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    return false
}

// The following property allows you to select cells while in editing mode
    self.tableView.allowsSelectionDuringEditing = true
```